# How to create auto complete in text box in semantic ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, user-interface, semantic-ui

I am using Semantic UI auto complete textbox.

```
$(document).ready(function(search) {
    $('.ui.search')
        .search({
            source: content
        });
    var content = [{
        title: 'Andorra'
    }, {
        title: 'United Arab Emirates'
    }, {
        title: 'Afghanistan'
    }, {
        title: 'Antigua'
    }, ];
});
```

This is the code i am using from the website of Semantic UI, but I'm getting an error in console as,

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).search is not a function

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you loading the plugin?

Comment: Have you loaded jQuery properly or any other plugins? Check the network tab if you are using Chrome to see if any files are getting an errors when attempting to load.

Comment: yeah included....                                                                                              <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/1.11.8/semantic.min.css"/>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudfla         re.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/1.11.8/semantic.min.js"></script>                                                                               These are the libraries i have included. Are there any other to be included?

Comment: Do i have to include any other libraries other than this or any syntax error? Network is ok

Answer (score 0):

Please try if the following code helps you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.10/semantic.min.js"></script>
    <link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.10/semantic.css" rel="stylesheet"/>  
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            var content = [{
                title: 'Andorra'
            }, {
                title: 'United Arab Emirates'
            }, {
                title: 'Afghanistan'
            }, {
                title: 'Antigua'
            },];

            $('.ui.search')
                .search({
                    type: 'standard',
                    source: content,
                    searchFields: ['title'],
                });

        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="ui search">
    <div class="ui icon input">
        <input class="prompt" placeholder="Search countries..." type="text">
        <i class="search icon"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="results"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```